# Realtime display using redis pubsub in ruby?

Tags: ruby, redis, publish-subscribe

I have stream of data coming to me via an http hit. I want to update data in realtime. I have started pushing HTTP hits data to a redis pubsub. Now I want to show it to users.

I want to update user's screen as soon as I get some data on redis channel. I want to use ruby as that is the language I am comfortable with.

Comment: Why not use 3rd party tool like pubnub or pusher?

Comment: why can't I use my own ? I do not want o use a third party for an internal application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use Sinatra's "stream" feature coupled with EventSource on the client side. Leaves IE out, though.

Here's some mostly functional server side code pulled from https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/examples/pubsub.rb (another option is https://github.com/pietern/hiredis-rb):

```
get '/the_stream', provides: 'text/event-stream' do
  stream :keep_open do |out|
    redis = Redis.new
    redis.subscribe(:channel1, :channel2) do |on|
      on.message do |channel, msg|
        out << "data: #{msg}\n\n" # This is an EventSource message
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Client side. Most modern browsers support EventSource, except IE:

```
var stream = new EventSource('/the_stream');
stream.onmessage = function(e) {
  alert("I just got this from the server: " + e.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of I know you can do this via `Faye` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333992/faye-or-redis-pubsub) out

There are couple approach If you wish you can try

1. I remember myself building a Long Polling server using thin and sinatra to achieve something like this now If u wish you can do the same
2. I know of few like [this](https://github.com/danielwanja/redis_flex) and [this](https://github.com/claus/as3redis) flash client that you can use to connect directly to redis
3. There is EventMachine Websocket implementation u can use and hook it up with HTML 5 and Flash for non HTML 5 browser
4. Websocket-Rack

Other Approach you can try just a suggestion since most of them arent written in ruby

1. Juggernaut ( I dont think it based on Redis Pub-sub Thing also there used to ruby thing earlier not sure of now)
2. [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)
3. [Webd.is](http://webd.is/)
4. [NULLMQ](https://github.com/progrium/nullmq) Not a redis pub sub but this is Zero MQ implementation in javascript

There are few other approach you can find If u google up :)

Hope this help